# How to repair irreparable files?

Tags: windows-8.1, cmd.exe, .net-framework, dism, .net-4.0

In Windows 8.1 `sfc /scannow` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` are unable to repair *"aspnet_state_perf.ini" "aspnet_perf2.ini" and "aspnet_perf.h"*.

which are part of "NetFx-AspNet-NonWow64-Shared".

CBS.log ([Full error log here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhadzxds2on5k4l/sfc.txt?dl=0))

```
2015-01-28 23:55:54, Info                  CSI    00000529 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:42{21}]"aspnet_state_perf.ini" of NetFx-AspNet-NonWow64-Shared, Version = 4.0.9600.17635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:b03f5f7f11d50a3a}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-01-28 23:55:54, Info                  CSI    0000052b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:32{16}]"aspnet_perf2.ini" of NetFx-AspNet-NonWow64-Shared, Version = 4.0.9600.17635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:b03f5f7f11d50a3a}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-01-28 23:55:54, Info                  CSI    0000052d [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:26{13}]"aspnet_perf.h" of NetFx-AspNet-NonWow64-Shared, Version = 4.0.9600.17635, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:b03f5f7f11d50a3a}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
```

The update package is:

```
"Package_3_for_KB2969357~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.35.2969357-692_neutral_GDR"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Change the source to a local source like an installation disk.

Comment: With `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:wim:e:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess` `e` is a USB Windows installer. Returns: `Error: 0x800f081f` The source files could not be found.

Comment: you must add the Update KB2969357 to the install.wim first with DISM

Comment: How magicandre?

Comment: Have you verified the package that your trying to repair exists on the disk?  If it doesn't then you will have to download the update manually, place it on the source disk, then run the command again.

Comment: Ramnhound `amd64_netfx-aspnet-nonwow64-shared_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.9600.17643`is not present in the RTM DVD or the older Windows 8.1 computer. Where else could I look for this folder?

Comment: I uninstalled `KB2969357 Update` in the Control Panel and it fixed the file errors. However `sfc /scannow` still reports being unable to repair some of the corrupt files. No particular file is labeled in the new [CBS.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2n2s5e8i3o4uj9/CBS.log?dl=0) which worries me. Can you give it a look [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2n2s5e8i3o4uj9/CBS.log?dl=0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling `Windows Update KB2969357` in the Control Panel fixed the corrupted files.

However `sfc /scannow` still reported not being able to repair some unnamed files. System Restore failed several times and added more errors to the table.

Ultimately I used a Windows 8.1 RTM DVD and choose Upgrade. Windows retained all programs and settings, plus no more integrity violations.

And the Windows folder shrinked from 24GBs to 14 GBs :)

Comment: Don't worry, it grows right back. :D SFC is good for important files repair (like main dlls), not all weird patched that come about.